# How can use I SqlCommand with a where clause in textbox?

Tags: asp.net

```
String strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ToString();
SqlConnection con;

protected void run_save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    String select = txtComand.Text;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        gridview1.DataSource = dr;
        gridview1.DataBind();
        con.Close();


 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtComand" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="227px" 
            Width="352px"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="idRun" OnClick="run_save" Text="RUN" />
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridview1"></asp:GridView>
```

i m writing sql comnd in text box..like as select*from test..here all data are showing in gridview..but i m writing select * from test where id=5..then is not working

Comment: Where is your SQL command?? The question is too vague to answer!!! Please add some more details as to what you are trying to achieve!!

Comment: does your textbox contains only where clause or complete command text?

Comment: can you show us your sql ?

Comment: select * from test where id=5

Comment: Do you actually have a row where ID equals 5?

Comment: yes i have...but data is not showing

Answer (score 1):

With your current Implementation, you need to enter complete Select Query with Where clause  in your TextBox Control: `txtCommand`, since you are reading the whole text of the `textCommand` into the `select` string which forms the SelectQuery .  One better way is to enter only the value to used in `Where` into your text box and append it to your actual SQLSelect Query:

```
string select= "Select * from test where ID=" + "'" +txtCommand.Text+ "'";
```

Note that the above simple way exposes a lots of ways for SQL Injection attacks.  So ***use this example just for startup and then implement your different ways for security***.